# What is an affine $0$ space?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, notation, definition, affine-geometry

I have encountered $\mathbb{A}^0$, where $\mathbb{A}^n$ is the affine $n$ space over some algebraically closed field. What exactly is $\mathbb{A}^0$? Does this only consist of $1$ element perhaps?

Comment: Sure, seems reasonable to call a point $\mathbb{A}^0$. Or maybe better $\operatorname{Spec} k$?

Comment: By all means. Pairs well with $\emptyset=\Bbb P^{-1}$ too.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I was a bit confused with this notation.